# How can I return the captured value in look ahead regex in R

Tags: r, regex

I am trying to capture the number in the string using this regex

```
gsub("\\d+(?= win)", "\\1", "1 win & 1 nomination", perl = TRUE)
```

I want to capture the value 1 (of 1 win) however `\\1` returns the string `win & 1 nomination` How can I get it to return the number 1 ?

Edit : I also need to capture the wins in string like:  Nominated for 2 Golden Globes. Another 21 wins & 72 nominations.

Sample strings and results :

- **String** : Nominated for 2 Golden Globes. Another 21 wins & 72 nominations. **Result** : 21
- **String** : 3 wins & 2 nominations. **Result** : 3
- **String** : Won 2 Oscars. Another 72 wins & 57 nominations. **Result**: 72

Comment: You can do something like `"(\\d+(?= win)).*"` (you haven't included the number in the group and you need to add `.*` in order to capture the rest of the string)

Comment: @DavidArenburg Thanks for your comment. But your regex doesn't match the other type of strings that I need to match. I've updated the edit sections with the other strings that I need to match. I tried using ".*(\\d+(?= win)).*" but that only matches 1 in the 21 of the other string and misses out 2.

Comment: Could do `.*?(\\d+(?= win)).*` perhaps.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Thanks this works :)

Comment: It works, but it makes absolutely no sense to use a lookahead here as `space` + `win` will be removed in the end and the only substring you will get in the result will be the digits. Due to the lookahead you need to use a PCRE regex while without it you may use a normal TRE regex and do not have to care if the string contains newlines or not.

Comment: I think you are confused by what `gsub` does with a pattern. It removes all non-overlapping matches from a string. To get matches, you need to use `regmatches` - that will fetch the substrings matched by the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
gsub("^(\\d+).*", "\\1", "1 win & 1 nomination")
[1] "1"
```

Comment: Your answer only captures the general case. I am sorry I should have included the other type of strings too that I need to match. Updated the question to include other details.

Comment: It will be helpful if you could provide simple sample and results you want.

Comment: Thanks @Shenglin Chen  for your resopnse. I've updated the answer with the samples.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution - `gsub("\\d+(?= win)", "\\1", "1 win & 1 nomination", perl = TRUE)` - does not work because you have no capturing group in your pattern and `\1` is empty. So, you effectively remove the 1+ digits that are before a space+`win`.

If you need to get the number before whitespace(s) and `win` or `wins` as whole words, use the following `regmatches` solution:

```
> x <- c("Nominated for 2 Golden Globes. Another 21 wins & 72 nominations.", "3 wins & 2 nominations.", "Won 2 Oscars. Another 72 wins & 57 nominations.")
> regmatches(x, regexpr("\\d+(?=\\s*wins?\\b)", x, perl=TRUE))
[1] "21" "3"  "72"
```

**Details**:

- `\\d+` - 1 or more digits
- `(?=\\s*wins?\\b)` - only if followed with

  - `\\s*` - 0 or more whitespaces
  - `wins?\\b` - and a whole word `win` or `wins`.

A solution with `sub` using another variation of your regex (that does not match `win` or `wins` as whole words) using a TRE regex (default  flavor):

```
> sub(".*?(\\d+)\\s*win.*", "\\1", x)
[1] "21" "3"  "72"
```

**Details**:

- `.*?` - matches any 0+ chars, *as few as possible* up to the first...
- `(\\d+)` - (Group 1 referred to with `\\1` later) - 1 or more digits
- `\\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `win` - a `win` char sequence
- `.*`  - any 0+ chars up to the end of the string.

Comment: Is it not possible to have capturing group with a look ahead? Also is gsub not the suitable function for capturing this kind of patterns? I didn't not understand why you used regmatches. I want to apply it to a vector.

Comment: I replaced the examples with a string to examples with a vector. If you are using a *replacing* approach with `sub`, the point is to *match and consume* what you do not want to keep, and match, consume and *capture* what you need to keep. With `regmatches`, you only need to *match and consume* what you need.